# RVM not reading .ruby-gemset files when I open a new tab in my terminal

Tags: ruby, rvm

I have a new install of RVM on Fedora 20.

If I cd to myapp, RVM will read the .ruby-gemset file and switch to the appropriate gemset, but if I open a new tab (control-shift-t) and run `rvm gemset list` I find that it's using the default gemset.

Does any have any idea what I might be doing wrong?

I've got the following in .bashrc

```
# .bashrc

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
    . /etc/bashrc
fi

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin:$HOME/.rvm/bin

export PATH
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

And I've got more ore less identical content in .bash_profile

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin:$HOME/.rvm/bin

export PATH

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

The terminal is the bog standard one that comes with Fedora.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue, and I was able to fix it. However, my exact solution might be useless for you. I had oh-my-zsh installed. It looks like during installation, it was trying to mimic my .bashrc files and it screwed PATH variable for me. Here's the line I had trouble with:

```
export PATH="/home/alexander/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@security/bin:/home/alexander/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1@global/bin:/home/alexander/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/bin:/home/alexander/.nvm/v0.10.25/bin:/home/alexander/work/gc-sdk/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/home/alexander/.rvm/bin"
```

So, you need to verify if your PATH variable isn't tempered with. And you need to let RVM configure it for you. Both these things can be done with a simple command in your terminal (assuming you have RVM installed):

```
rvm get stable --auto-dotfiles
```

Also, there're couple of issues created on [GitHub](https://github.com/wayneeseguin/rvm/issues/2519). The common advice is to use command from above and switch your terminal to login shell.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, this didn't worked for me too. And now the gemset is not loading even after doing `cd ..` and `cd <my_dir>`    :(

Comment: Also not working for me. But instead of `cd ..` and `cd <my_dir>` you can do just `cd .`.

Answer (score 13):

Putting `cd .` to `~/.profile` fixed the issue for me.

If you are using zsh, put `cd .` to `~/.zlogin`.

Comment: Thanks - This is very simple and useful

Comment: In Ubuntu 14.04, I have added  `cd .` at bottom of file `~/.bashrc` and it worked. 

Thanks @TeWu

Answer (score 0):

Go to:
Preferences(Locate it by clicking bars at the Top-Right immediately after the search icon) -> Choose Your Profile(Located left at the bottom) If you don't have a profile then you can add a new one by clicking the plus icon that precedes the name profiles -> Click on 'Command'(Located at the top) -> Check by clicking the checkbox that states, 'Run command as a login shell'

That worked for me.